# I get NuGet error when trying to install any package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm making a Windows form progect in Visual Studio.
When I trying to install any package through console I get error

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'PackageName' at source ''.
> I tried both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2019.

When I go to Nuget Browse I get error as well. I don't see any packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you can check your package scources under Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager if you don’t have the correct package sources you can add this “https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json” such as:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add `-source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"` behind?